# Display zero in group by sql for a particular period

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run the following query to obtain the sales for each type of job for a particular period. However for certain months where there are no jobs of a particular job type performed no 0 is displayed in sales.

How can i display the zeros in such a condition.

Here is the sql query-

```
select Year(postedOn), month(postedOn), jobType, sum(price)
from tbl_jobs
group by jobType, year(postedOn), month(postedOn)
order by jobType, year(postedOn), month(postedOn)
```

Comment: You can create a calendar table and do outer joining to fill the gaps

Comment: Yes i did that :-) thank you

Comment: Generally, issues of data display are best resolved in application level code. If that's available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, this is where your all-purpose calendar or numbers table comes in to anchor the query with a consistent sequential set:

```
SELECT job_summary.*
FROM Calendar
CROSS JOIN (
    -- you may not have though about this part of the problem, though
    -- what about years/months with missing job types?
    SELECT distinct jobType FROM tbl_jobs
) AS job_types
LEFT JOIN (
    select Year(postedOn) AS year,month(postedOn) as month,jobType ,sum(price)
    from tbl_jobs
    group by jobType, year(postedOn), month(postedOn)
) job_summary
    ON job_summary.jobType = job_types.jobType
    AND job_summary.year = Calendar.year
    AND job_summary.month = Calendar.month
WHERE Calendar.day = 1 -- Assuming your calendar is every day
    AND calendar.date BETWEEN some_range_goes_here -- you don't want all time, right?
order by job_types.jobType, Calendar.year, Calendar.month
```

Comment: @VarunMallya if the answer worked for you, you should accept it :-)